# Implementing hierarchical DB tables with InheritanceType.JOINED and a `tenant_id` column in every table

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, relational-database, multi-tenant

I'm trying to implement a hierarchical structure using the `InheritanceType.JOINED` approach to store data in hierarchical DB tables. One caveat is that in our multi-tenant solution, a `tenant_id` column needs to be present *on every table* (for security and legal export reasons), even though this is redundant in some cases. This requirement is fixed.

Issue is that when inserting data, the query Hibernate generates does not fill in the `tenant_id` on the parent- and childtable, causing a constraint error.

The tables in the DB would look like this:
[image]

Code for the abstract vehicle entity:

```kotlin
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
abstract class Vehicle(
    var tenantId: Int,
    var title: String
)
```

Car entity:

```kotlin
@Entity
class Car(
    override var tenantId: Int,
    override var title: String,
) : Vehicle(tenantId, title) {

    var numberOfDoors: Int
}
```

Plane entity:

```kotlin
@Entity
class Plane(
    override var tenantId: Int,
    override var title: String,
) : Vehicle(tenantId, title) {

    var numberOfPropellers: Int
}
```

When inserting a new Car in the database, Hibernate generates 2 queries, where the `tenant_id` is only added to the abstract Vehicle table:

```sql
insert into vehicle (tenant_id, title) values (?, ?)

insert into car (id, number_of_doors) values (?, ?)
```

**Is there a way to instruct Hibernate to fill in the column on both tables?**

One hack I've found is to implement a "second" `tenantId` variable on the class and specify a column explicitly, as such:

```kotlin
@Column(name = "tenant_id")
private val _tenantId: Int = tenantId
```

But it's not very clean and a neater solution would be nice.

Comment: You'll need the hack as JPA cannot see the tenantId from the super class - by overriding it, you are replacing it so there is only the one mapping/column. You'd also need special setters/getters to make it easier for the app to set both properties in the object anyway. There are other non-JPA mapping types that might allow you to have this one tenantId property mapped to two DB columns (EclipseLink's concept of a transformation mapping: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/mappingintro001.htm ) but I don't know the hibernate equivalent, or that there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically in my case where the `tenant_id` column is a database setting, defining a computed default value on the `tenant_id` db column also works as a workaround:

```
current_setting('app.current_tenant', true)::INT
```